# jQuery each() function not looping through elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery.each() function is not looping through buttons.

Debugger stops on the first line of the function call, but it doesn't ***execute*** the function

Code was used from [bootstrap-calendar](https://github.com/Serhioromano/bootstrap-calendar)

app.js contains the following each() functions:

```
$('.btn-group button[data-calendar-nav]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.click(function() {
        calendar.navigate($this.data('calendar-nav'));
    });
});

$('.btn-group button[data-calendar-view]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.click(function() {
        calendar.view($this.data('calendar-view'));
    });
});
```

HTML divs and buttons:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="pull-right form-inline">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-calendar-nav="prev"><< Prev</button>
            <button class="btn" data-calendar-nav="today">Today</button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-warning" data-calendar-view="year">Year</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning active" data-calendar-view="month">Month</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Initialization script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var calendar = $('#calendar').calendar({
    events_source: [
        {
            "id": 293,
            "title": "Event 1",
            "url": "http://example.com",
            "class": "event-important",
            "start": 1437507900000, // Milliseconds 
            "end":   1437508639654 // Milliseconds
        }
    ],
    tmpl_path: "tmpls/"

    });
</script>
```

*** UPDATE ***

Found the solution. Problem was that app.js (contains the jQuery each() functions) was declared in the head, but it needs to be declared after the HTML and script for it to work properly.

Wrong order:

- app.js
- HTML
- script

Good order:

- HTML
- script
- app.js

Comment: Can you expand on what the issue is? It works for me.

Comment: IN the click handler? That won't happen until you click the element.

Comment: working fine with jquery version 2.1.1

Comment: On a side note, you must move the `click` handlers out of the each loop as `jQuery` does that for you. And also, you can merge your code in to fewer lines/remove each loop as well, something like: `$('.btn-group button').on("click", function() {...`

Answer (score 1):

your selector is ok.

if i do a

```
$('.btn-group button[data-calendar-nav]').each(function(index) {
  var $this = $(this);
  console.log($this.data('calendar-nav'));
});
```

i get

```
prev
today
next
```

so your problem lies in the usage of calendar.navigate

if i debug it with firebug, i get `TypeError: calendar.navigate is not a function`.
so maybe your variable `calendar` is not known to the function.

Comment: `TypeError` means the variable is found, but `.navigate` probably isn't a valid function. `ReferenceError` would be showing if the variable didn't exist.